# GitVersion incrementing Major and Minor versions but not Patch

Tags: git, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, semantic-versioning, gitversion

We are trying to overhaul our GitVersion setup and for some reason the Patch version is not incrementing in our release branches, either automatically or explicitly with `+semver: patch`.  It does seem to work on the main branch.

This is a .NET application that automatically builds in a Azure DevOps pipeline - we are using the GitVersion plugin (spec 5.2.4).

The GitVersion.yml file has gone through multiple iterations but this is where it sits currently:

```
mode: Mainline
assembly-versioning-scheme: MajorMinorPatch
assembly-file-versioning-scheme: MajorMinorPatch
assembly-informational-format: '{Major}.{Minor}.{Patch}.{PreReleaseNumber}'
commit-message-incrementing: Enabled
major-version-bump-message: '\+semver:\s?(breaking|major)'
minor-version-bump-message: '\+semver:\s?(feature|minor)'
patch-version-bump-message: '\+semver:\s?(fix|patch)'
no-bump-message: '\+semver:\s?(none|skip)'

branches:
  main:
    tag: ''
    increment: Patch
    prevent-increment-of-merged-branch-version: true
    track-merge-target: false
    regex: (^main$|^origin\/main$)
    source-branches:
    - main
    tracks-release-branches: false
    is-release-branch: false
    is-mainline: true
    pre-release-weight: 55000
  release:
    tag: 'R'
    increment: Patch
    prevent-increment-of-merged-branch-version: false
    track-merge-target: false
    regex: ^release?[/-]
    source-branches: []
    tracks-release-branches: true
    is-release-branch: true
    is-mainline: true
    pre-release-weight: 30000
ignore:
  sha: [8d1c309fd0baeaef867d152c29c288dd33e39963, 579819d0984b415313f388a2c2e36e284ee7254a, 80d0ac18b26d0fd21220f0d915d8d242eda311a7] 
merge-message-formats: {}
```

This is the output of `dotnet-gitversion`:

```
{
  "Major": 4,
  "Minor": 12,
  "Patch": 5,
  "PreReleaseTag": "R.158",
  "PreReleaseTagWithDash": "-R.158",
  "PreReleaseLabel": "R",
  "PreReleaseLabelWithDash": "-R",
  "PreReleaseNumber": 158,
  "WeightedPreReleaseNumber": 30158,
  "BuildMetaData": null,
  "BuildMetaDataPadded": "",
  "FullBuildMetaData": "Branch.release-TestBranch2.Sha.ec21cfb055ad846aad5efa07626b497462c59daa",
  "MajorMinorPatch": "4.12.5",
  "SemVer": "4.12.5-R.158",
  "LegacySemVer": "4.12.5-R158",
  "LegacySemVerPadded": "4.12.5-R0158",
  "AssemblySemVer": "4.12.5.0",
  "AssemblySemFileVer": "4.12.5.0",
  "FullSemVer": "4.12.5-R.158",
  "InformationalVersion": "4.12.5.158",
  "BranchName": "release/TestBranch2",
  "EscapedBranchName": "release-TestBranch2",
  "Sha": "ec21cfb055ad846aad5efa07626b497462c59daa",
  "ShortSha": "ec21cfb",
  "NuGetVersionV2": "4.12.5-r0158",
  "NuGetVersion": "4.12.5-r0158",
  "NuGetPreReleaseTagV2": "r0158",
  "NuGetPreReleaseTag": "r0158",
  "VersionSourceSha": "0872f890ce6508fcc7501e85876d0cb650bebf4f",
  "CommitsSinceVersionSource": 158,
  "CommitsSinceVersionSourcePadded": "0158",
  "UncommittedChanges": 0,
  "CommitDate": "2023-01-11"
}
```

- Tried toggling the following values:

```
tracks-release-branches
is-release-branch
is-mainline
```

- Also played with the regex, adding .* at the end

Unsure what should go under source-branches, should this be the regex again?

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!